# No value given for one or more required parameters. System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException:

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, vb.net, ms-access

I am getting this error while running my aspx file when I click o Button2 after selecting start and end date and value from dropdown list.
The website was working normally but now it is throwing this exception. 
My Aspx code is as follows

```
<center><p style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
            START DATE AND TIME&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="181px"  BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<img src="calender.png" /></p></center> 
      <center>   <p style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
            END DATE&nbsp;AND TIME&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="188px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<img src="calender.png" />
        </p>
        </center>

            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <center style="height: 40px"> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT AND CALCULATE" onclick="btnSave_Click1" BackColor="#FF9966"  CssClass="btn btn-large" Font-Bold="True"/>
              <br />
```

```
        <td>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" Height="146px" Width="53px" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="stdev_POLQA_score" HeaderText="stdev_POLQA_score" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="stdev_POLQA_score" >
            <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
    </asp:GridView></td></tr></table>

         <br />
         <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" BackColor="#FF9966" Text="EXPORT POLQA TO EXCEL" CssClass="btn btn-large" Font-Bold="True" />
         <br />

     <br />
   <table><tr> <td>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" Height="146px" Width="53px" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="mean_RTD" HeaderText="mean_RTD" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="mean_RTD" >
            <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" BackColor="White" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
    </asp:GridView></td>

    <br /><td>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" Height="146px" Width="53px" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="STDEV_RTD" HeaderText="stdev_RTD" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="STDEV_RTD" >
            <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" BackColor="White" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
    </asp:GridView></td>

    <br />

            </tr>  </table>
          </center>
    <br />


    <center> <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="EXPORT RTD TO EXCEL" onclick="Button3_Click" BackColor="#FF9966"  CssClass="btn btn-large" Font-Bold="True" Width="257px"/>
    </center>
    <br />

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ROUND(AVG(POLQA_Score),3) AS mean_POLQA_score FROM VQTPOLQA WHERE VQT_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND VQuad_PhoneID =?">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" DefaultValue="" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" DefaultValue="" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="?" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <br />

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ROUND(AVG(RTD),3) AS mean_RTD FROM VQuadData WHERE VQuad_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND RTD&gt;0 AND  VQuad_PhoneID=?">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" DefaultValue="" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" DefaultValue="" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="?" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM VQTPOLQA WHERE VQT_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND VQuadPhone_ID=?">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="?" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ROUND(Stdev(RTD),3) AS STDEV_RTD FROM VQuadData WHERE VQuad_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND? AND RTD&gt;0 AND VQuad_PhoneID=?">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" DefaultValue="" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" DefaultValue="" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="?" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource7" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM VQuadData WHERE VQuad_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND VQuad_PhoneID=?">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="?" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ROUND(Stdev(POLQA_score),3) AS stdev_POLQA_score FROM VQTPOLQA WHERE VQT_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND  VQuad_PhoneID=?">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" DefaultValue="" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" DefaultValue="" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="?" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <br />
    <br />

   <div style="display:none" ><center> <asp:GridView ID="GridView5" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VQT_Timestamp" HeaderText="VQT_Timestamp" SortExpression="VQT_Timestamp" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VQuad_Timestamp" HeaderText="VQuad_Timestamp" SortExpression="VQuad_Timestamp" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GPS_Position" HeaderText="GPS_Position" SortExpression="GPS_Position" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GPS_Lat" HeaderText="GPS_Lat" SortExpression="GPS_Lat" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GPS_Long" HeaderText="GPS_Long" SortExpression="GPS_Long" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VQuad_CallID" HeaderText="VQuad_CallID" SortExpression="VQuad_CallID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VQuad_Location" HeaderText="VQuad_Location" SortExpression="VQuad_Location" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VQuad_PhoneID" HeaderText="VQuad_PhoneID" SortExpression="VQuad_PhoneID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Degraded" HeaderText="Degraded" SortExpression="Degraded" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Deg_File_Name" HeaderText="Deg_File_Name" SortExpression="Deg_File_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="POLQA_Score" HeaderText="POLQA_Score" SortExpression="POLQA_Score" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Pass_Or_Fail" HeaderText="Pass_Or_Fail" SortExpression="Pass_Or_Fail" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Jitter_Min" HeaderText="Jitter_Min" SortExpression="Jitter_Min" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Jitter_Max" HeaderText="Jitter_Max" SortExpression="Jitter_Max" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Jitter_Ave" HeaderText="Jitter_Ave" SortExpression="Jitter_Ave" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EModel_Polqa" HeaderText="EModel_Polqa" SortExpression="EModel_Polqa" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Speech_Level_Diff" HeaderText="Speech_Level_Diff" SortExpression="Speech_Level_Diff" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SNR_Diff" HeaderText="SNR_Diff" SortExpression="SNR_Diff" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ASR_Ref" HeaderText="ASR_Ref" SortExpression="ASR_Ref" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ASR_Deg" HeaderText="ASR_Deg" SortExpression="ASR_Deg" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Number_of_Utterance" HeaderText="Number_of_Utterance" SortExpression="Number_of_Utterance" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Call_Timestamp" HeaderText="Call_Timestamp" SortExpression="Call_Timestamp" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CallType_Orig" HeaderText="CallType_Orig" SortExpression="CallType_Orig" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CallType_Term" HeaderText="CallType_Term" SortExpression="CallType_Term" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
    </asp:GridView></center></div>

    <br />

    <div style="display:none"><center><asp:GridView ID="GridView6" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VQuad_Timestamp" HeaderText="VQuad_Timestamp" SortExpression="VQuad_Timestamp" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GPS_Position" HeaderText="GPS_Position" SortExpression="GPS_Position" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GPS_Lat" HeaderText="GPS_Lat" SortExpression="GPS_Lat" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GPS_Long" HeaderText="GPS_Long" SortExpression="GPS_Long" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AFT" HeaderText="AFT" SortExpression="AFT" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RTD" HeaderText="RTD" SortExpression="RTD" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RTD_Error" HeaderText="RTD_Error" SortExpression="RTD_Error" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PDD" HeaderText="PDD" SortExpression="PDD" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PDD_Error" HeaderText="PDD_Error" SortExpression="PDD_Error" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone_ID" HeaderText="Phone_ID" SortExpression="Phone_ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Call_Control_Event" HeaderText="Call_Control_Event" SortExpression="Call_Control_Event" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VQuad_CallID" HeaderText="VQuad_CallID" SortExpression="VQuad_CallID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VQuad_Location" HeaderText="VQuad_Location" SortExpression="VQuad_Location" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VQuad_PhoneID" HeaderText="VQuad_PhoneID" SortExpression="VQuad_PhoneID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Call_Timestamp" HeaderText="Call_Timestamp" SortExpression="Call_Timestamp" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RTD_Rating" HeaderText="RTD_Rating" SortExpression="RTD_Rating" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OWD" HeaderText="OWD" SortExpression="OWD" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SWR" HeaderText="SWR" SortExpression="SWR" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CC_Condition" HeaderText="CC_Condition" SortExpression="CC_Condition" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CallType_Orig" HeaderText="CallType_Orig" SortExpression="CallType_Orig" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CallType_Term" HeaderText="CallType_Term" SortExpression="CallType_Term" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView></center></div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:AccessDataSource runat="server" DataFile="C:\Users\saishnib\Desktop\VQT DB LATEST ORIGINAL (copy)\New folder\VQT.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT AVG(POLQA_Score) AS MEANPOLQA FROM VQTPOLQA WHERE (VQT_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" DefaultValue="" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VQTConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [VQuad_PhoneID] FROM [VQTPOLQA]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
```

My aspx.vb code is as follows

```
    Protected Sub btnSave_Click1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim connectionString As [String] = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data" + " Source=C:\Users\saishnib\Desktop\VQT DB LATEST ORIGINAL (copy)\New folder\VQT.mdb"
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        conn.Open()

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ROUND(AVG(POLQA_Score),3) AS MEANPOLQA FROM VQTPOLQA WHERE VQT_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND VQuad_PhoneID =?", conn)

        Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ROUND(AVG(RTD),3) AS mean_RTD FROM VQuadData WHERE VQuad_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND RTD>0 AND  VQuad_PhoneID=?", conn)

        Dim cmd3 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Stdev(RTD) AS STDEV_RTD FROM VQuadData WHERE VQuad_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND RTD>0 VQuad_PhoneID =?", conn)

        Dim cmd4 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Stdev(POLQA_Score) AS STDEV_POLQA FROM VQTPOLQA WHERE VQT_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? VQuad_PhoneID =?", conn)


        Dim param As OleDbParameter
        param = cmd.CreateParameter
        param.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
        param.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
        param.ParameterName = "@StartDate"
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

        Dim param1 As OleDbParameter
        param1 = cmd.CreateParameter
        param1.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
        param1.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
        param1.ParameterName = "@EndDate"
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1)

        GridView1.DataBind()

        Dim param2 As OleDbParameter
        param2 = cmd2.CreateParameter
        param2.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
        param2.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
        param2.ParameterName = "@StartDate"
        cmd2.Parameters.Add(param2)

        Dim param3 As OleDbParameter
        param3 = cmd2.CreateParameter
        param3.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
        param3.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
        param3.ParameterName = "@EndDate"
        cmd2.Parameters.Add(param3)

        GridView2.DataBind()

        Dim param4 As OleDbParameter
        param4 = cmd3.CreateParameter
        param4.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
        param4.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
        param4.ParameterName = "@StartDate"
        cmd3.Parameters.Add(param4)

        Dim param5 As OleDbParameter
        param5 = cmd3.CreateParameter
        param5.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
        param5.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
        param5.ParameterName = "@EndDate"
        cmd3.Parameters.Add(param5)

        GridView3.DataBind()


        Dim param6 As OleDbParameter
        param6 = cmd4.CreateParameter
        param6.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
        param6.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
        param6.ParameterName = "@StartDate"
        cmd4.Parameters.Add(param6)

        Dim param7 As OleDbParameter
        param7 = cmd4.CreateParameter
        param7.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
        param7.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
        param7.ParameterName = "@EndDate"
        cmd4.Parameters.Add(param7)

        GridView4.DataBind()


        conn.Close()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Response.Clear()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
        Dim stringWrite As New System.IO.StringWriter()
        Dim htmlWrite As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)
        GridView6.RenderControl(htmlWrite)
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString())
        Response.[End]()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)
        Return
    End Sub


    Protected Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Response.Clear()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
        Dim stringWrite As New System.IO.StringWriter()
        Dim htmlWrite As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)
        GridView5.RenderControl(htmlWrite)
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString())
        Response.[End]()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Ok what is question? Which line of code is throwing exception? Did you debug the code??

Comment: Hi Chetan I am getting this error while loading website No value given for one or more required parameters. How do I rectify it?

Comment: Share the page_load code too. Which line of code is giving error?

Comment: It's on this part I think `Protected Sub btnSave_Click1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click`

Comment: `Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub`

Comment: You need to debug and check which line is giving error. You have multiple commands executing in click event. You need to debug and see which one is failing.

Comment: `GridView2.DataBind()` th part is giving error I was debugging

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya I am still not understanding the cause of the error

Comment: Each of your command is expecting 3 parameter, yet you are only passing 2 parameters to them. See you have 3 ? in your sql statement. `Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ROUND(AVG(POLQA_Score),3) AS MEANPOLQA FROM VQTPOLQA WHERE VQT_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND VQuad_PhoneID =?", conn)`

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b I am already having three ? in my query.

Comment: @Snb93 You are only passing 2 parameters `Dim param As OleDbParameter
        param = cmd.CreateParameter
        param.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
        param.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
        param.ParameterName = "@StartDate"
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

        Dim param1 As OleDbParameter
        param1 = cmd.CreateParameter
        param1.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
        param1.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
        param1.ParameterName = "@EndDate"
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1)`

Answer (score 0):

After editing the SQL DATA source that is attached to the particular GridView we can modify the ? content to be Control TextBox and DropDown by using the ideal SQL query this solves the issue.